# How can I create a <li> inside a jsp page retrieving string values from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, tags, html-lists, struts

I am developing a web app inside Eclipse, using struts2. I have an action class that creates an array full of string.

How can I realize a `<li>` inside the jsp I call retrieving string values from my array?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **iterator** struts tag. 
Example :

```
<ul>
        <s:iteratorvalue="somevalue">
            <li>
                <s:property/>
            </li>
            <li>
            <s:propertyvalue="somevalue"/>
            </li>
        </s:iterator>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Check the official link here : https://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator-tag-examples.html?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C4315720464